# Extjs Combobox focusout event not being called

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, combobox

I have 3 sibling divs like below.

```
`<div>div1</div>
 <div>div2 (Contains Extjs Combo)</div>
 <div>div3</div>
```

'
if the picker of combo is visible and i click on the ancestral elements of div2 the picker collapsed, but if i click on div1 or div2 it does not collapse.
no focusout event is fired.

Comment: can you please put your efforts on [secha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor)?

Comment: Did you perhaps meant [blur](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#event-blur) instead of focusout?